# Deleting consecutively duplicated data

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe where I wanna delete data that appear two times consecutively in two columns, (its ok if it appear two times by row)

basically I wanna go from that:

```
df1<-data.frame(col1=c("a","a"),col2=c("b","b"),col3=c("b","b"),col4=c("e","e"),col5=c("b","b"))

  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
x1  a    b   b    e    b
x2  a    b   b    e    b
```

to that:

```
df2<-data.frame(col1=c("a","a"),col2=c("b","b"),col3=c(NA,NA),col4=c("e","e"),col5=c("b","b"))

  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
x1  a    b   NA    e    b
x2  a    b   NA    e    b
```

or eventually that:

```
df3<-data.frame(col1=c("a","a"),col2=c("b","b"),col3=c("e","e"),col4=c("b","b"),col5=c(NA,NA))

  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
x1  a   b    e    b   NA
x2  a   b    e    b   NA
```

you can see only data that appear two times consecutively by column disappear and not by row

here what it would look like if i expend it:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
x1  a   b    b    e    b    d
x2  a   b    b    e    b    d
x3  a   b    c    d    e    e
```

how I want it to change:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
x1  a   b    NA    e    b    d
x2  a   b    NA    e    b    d
x3  a   b    c     d    e   NA
```

df1   https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufUjq.png

df2   https://i.stack.imgur.com/gluIl.png

df3   https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZH5j.png

Comment: Hi Leonardo, welcome to SO. To increase the quantity/quality of answers please post your data with `dput(data)` instead of pictures.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In addition to replacing the images with code for reproducible data, could you expand on your example? What would your desired dataset look like if there was a 3rd row with values a, b, c, d, and e across columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a slightly modified data set where I added a third repeated field (see if the result is right in this case), using `t`ranspose and `lag` to check the previous values, then transposing back also adjusting the row names.

##### mod. data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("a", "a", "a"), col2 = c("b", "b", "b"
), col3 = c("b", "b", "c"), col4 = c("b", "e", "e"), col5 = c("c", 
"b", "e")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

df1
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1    a    b    b    b    c
2    a    b    b    e    b
3    a    b    c    e    e
```

```
library(dplyr)

data.frame(t(df1)) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ if_else(.x == lag(.x, default=""), NA, .x))) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  data.frame(row.names = NULL)
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1    a    b <NA> <NA>    c
2    a    b <NA>    e    b
3    a    b    c    e <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found out a less efficient way to do it with a function:

```
supress_near_duplicate_word <- function(dataframe) {
  k=0
  dataframe <- replace(dataframe, is.na(dataframe), "")
  while (k<nrow(dataframe)){
    k=k+1
    i=0
    while (i<ncol(dataframe)) {
      i=i+1
      if(length(dataframe[k,i+1]) > 0 && dataframe[k,i]!="" && dataframe[k,i+1] == dataframe[k,i]){
        dataframe[k,i+1]<-"to_del"
      }
      }
    }
  return(dataframe)
}
```

it replace everything that appear two times consecutively (but not that appear 3 times the answer above is better) by to_del then just use !gsub() or st_remove (with stingr package)